# Form POST is returning null model

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to save a model to my database via a form post. Here's how the model looks like:

```
public class CreditCard
{
    public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
    public UserDetails userDetails { get; set; }
}

public class CardDetails
{
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the view that displays the form, I'm using a view component for each object in `CreditCard`:

```
@model CreditCard

<form asp-controller="Card" asp-action="Save" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn bg-blue"></button>

    @await Component.InvokeAsync("CardDetails", Model.cardDetails)
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("UserDetails", Model.userDetails)
</form>
```

CardDetails component:

```
@model CardDetails

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNumber)
</div>
```

This works fine, i.e the components get the data from the database and the fields are populated just fine. However when I try to POST via the save button, it returns null. Here's the action (which does hit successfully, but the parameter has both `cardDetails` and `userDetails` as null:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(CreditCard creditCard)
{
      // do stuff but creditCard.cardDetails and creditCard.userDetails are both null
}
```

Can someone figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab) and show us the payload being POSTed to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a different body to the server than it is set to consume.

`Save` takes `CreditCard` as an argument, but you're first sending a `CardDetails` object and then a `UserDetails` object.

You either need two different `Save()`, one taking `CardDetails` and one taking `UserDetails` or you construct the `CreditCard` object client-side before sending.

Comment: Thanks but how would I create the object client side? Would it be in the view that invokes the components?

Comment: @JoeDefill That’s right. Where you perform two calls, create a new CreditCard and populate the two fields with the ones from the Model.

Comment: I can't seem to get it right, do you have a code example? I couldn't find anyone doing the same thing

Comment: I realized I may have misunderstood the original question. When you say it returns null, what is "it"?

Comment: Sorry, the parameter `CreditCard creditCard` ends up having null  `CardDetails` and `UserDetails`